# Confusion about Elsevier template

Tags: templates, elsarticle, journal-publishing

I'm making my journal using [Elsevier latex template](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions). Here is an example of PDF output file:
[image]

However, I've reviewed some papers from Elsevier, and I can see the difference. For example:
[image]

How can I create the PDF file similar to the second picture?
Thanks.

Comment: I've never published with Elsevier, but if that's the template they asked you to use, that's probably what they want. You could email the journal editor and ask.

Comment: You are providing (hopefully good) content, they take care of presenting your content. Simple division of labour.

Comment: To clarify: are you making your own journal using the Elsevier template, as it is stated above or are you trying to publish with some Elsevier journal?

Comment: @engineer I'm trying to submit to a Elsevier journal, especially telematics and informatics.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The template that you see in articles is the one you get in the final form. What is officially available from Elsevier for authors cannot be used to create what you see in the second picture, but you can get closer to it using the following option in the document class command:

```
[final, 5p, times, authoryear, twocolumn]
```

For authoryear citations, you will need to use `abbrvnat` for bibliography style. For numbered citations, remove the authoryear option and use `elsart-num` for bibliography style.

```
\documentclass[final, 5p, times, authoryear, twocolumn]{elsarticle}


\begin{document}


\begin{frontmatter}

    % Paper title
    \title{Development of a Generalized PV Model in MATLAB/Simulink Using Datasheet Values}

    % Author names and emails
    \author{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh} \ead{almotasem.aldaoudeye@ndsu.edu}

    % University address
    \address{North Dakota State University, Fargo, ND, 58102}



    \begin{abstract}

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules \cite on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    \end{abstract}



    \begin{keyword}

        % Keywords

    \end{keyword}


\end{frontmatter}





\section{Introduction}
\label{section:introduction}

Solar photovoltaics (PV) is one of the fastest growing power industries in the world thanks to its appealing merits, like the widespread accessibility to natural solar resources, high reliability, easy integration into buildings and structures, fast installation, modularity, and predictable annual output \cite{luque2011}. Between 2000 and 2013, total PV production has been experiencing annual growth rates between $40\%$ and $90\%$ reaching an overall increase of two orders of magnitude. By 2010, thin film PV technologies accounted for around $13\%$ of the PV market share. The values were distributed as follows: $5\%$ for a-Si, for $2\%$ Copper indium di-selenide/Copper indium gallium selenide (CIS/CIGS), and $6\%$ for Cadmium Telluride / Cadmium sulfide (CdTe/CdS) \cite{tyagi2013}. However, most of the efforts in modeling PV modules focus on modules on crystalline silicon (c-Si) cells technology which exhibits characteristics closer to ideal cells. Thus, it is necessary to develop generalized models suitable for different types of technologies. \footnote{this is a footenote test}


Reference \cite{sera2007} derives expressions for several parameters given in a typical data sheet. Since the parameters of interest (series resistance, shunt resistance, and ideality factor) cannot be separated according to the given work, the authors devise an iterative algorithm to estimate these parameters. The algorithm keeps updating the shunt and series resistances, which adjusts the ideality factor accordingly. The process is repeated until all equations are satisfied.


% ===== The bibliography =====

%\bibliographystyle{elsart-num} % (For numbered Elsevier citations)
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} % (For authoryear Elsevier citations)

% The bibliography file
\bibliography{motasem_bib}



\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I have name for multiple authors at top but only one email Id and bottom. Also, multiple affiliations of author?