# Recent Elsevier latex template

Tags: templates, journal

I need the following template for Elsevier journal, which can generate a paper like the one in the image

P.S. I have tried to download it from the Elsevier site but I could not found it...
[image]

Comment: Are you sumbitting an article to Elsevier or you just want to copy the template because you like it?

Comment: I need it to submit a paper

Comment: Then don't waste your time trying to copy that layout. Use [`elsarticle`](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf) as recommended in the author guidelines. The final formatting of the article is done by their staff, regardless of what template you use. Take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375007/134574) for an example.